# How to get NULL or Zero values in SQL Server results set

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Trying to get the output of all mentioned accounts(total of 9) even though there are no existing records for the `GB.periode = 11`

Tried using `ISNULL(SUM(GB.bdr_val), 0)` but still I'm only getting output for `GB.reknr = 5210 OR GB.reknr = 5211 OR GB.reknr = 5250 OR GB.reknr = 5340`.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(GB.bdr_val) AS Total_Material_M, 
    GR.oms25_0 AS Desc2, GB.reknr AS Account
FROM
    [100].[dbo].[gbkmut] GB 
INNER JOIN 
    [100].[dbo].[grtbk] GR ON GB.reknr = GR.reknr
WHERE
    GB.bkjrcode = 2021 
    AND GB.periode = 11 
    AND (GB.reknr = 5000 OR GB.reknr = 5050 OR GB.reknr = 5150 OR 
         GB.reknr = 5200 OR GB.reknr = 5210 OR GB.reknr = 5211 OR 
         GB.reknr = 5250 OR GB.reknr = 5340 OR GB.reknr = 5341)
GROUP BY 
    GR.oms25_0,GB.reknr
ORDER BY 
    GB.reknr ASC
```

I have a sample DB layout below,

```
CREATE TABLE gbkmut
(
    id INT,
    reknr INT,
    bdr_val INT,
    bkjrcode INT,
    periode INT
);

INSERT INTO gbkmut VALUES (1, 5210, 3511, 2021, 11);
INSERT INTO gbkmut VALUES (2, 5211, -40, 2021, 11);
INSERT INTO gbkmut VALUES (3, 5250, 33832, 2021, 11);
INSERT INTO gbkmut VALUES (3, 5340, -16, 2021, 11);

CREATE TABLE grtbk 
(
    id INT,
    reknr INT,
    oms25_0 varchar(60)
);

INSERT INTO grtbk VALUES (1, 5210, 'Description 1');
INSERT INTO grtbk VALUES (2, 5211, 'Description 2');
INSERT INTO grtbk VALUES (3, 5250, 'Description 3');
INSERT INTO grtbk VALUES (4, 5340, 'Description 4');
INSERT INTO grtbk VALUES (5, 5000, 'Description 5');
INSERT INTO grtbk VALUES (6, 5050, 'Description 6');
INSERT INTO grtbk VALUES (7, 5150, 'Description 7');
INSERT INTO grtbk VALUES (8, 5200, 'Description 8');
INSERT INTO grtbk VALUES (9, 5341, 'Description 9');
```

I still need the query output to show all the `Total_Material_M`, `Desc2` and `Account` columns to show up even the values are `0` for specific `bkjrcode` and `periode` value combinations and `SUMS`, not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Please also share your desired results. given your sample data with values `5210, 5211, 5250, 5340` Are you also expecting this to show `RB.reknr` `5000` even though it isn't in your `gbkmut` table?  Desired results would help us understand further.

Comment: If you want a query that is going to return rows that are NOT in your table you can't select from that table. There is no select query that is going to generate rows. You would probably need a table, temp table, table variable or a cte that contains values for the missing rows. Then do a left join to your main table.

Comment: @JNevill my end goal results would be to display all the above mentioned 9 of those GB.reknr from 5000 to 5341 (among the thousands of other reknr values in the gbkmut table) and for given 'bkjrcode' and 'periode' parameters the results should show total of 9 rows. Even the 'Total_Material_M' value is Zero for the given parameters it should show '0' for 'Total_Material_M' column. Now 'Desc2' and 'Account' columns shouldn't have any issues since it's pulling data out from 'grtbk' table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE results(
Total_Material_M INT,
Desc2 VARCHAR(60),
Account INT
);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (152,'Description 1',5210);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (-25,'Description 2',5211);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (678,'Description 3',5250);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (354,'Description 4',5340);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (0,'Description 5',5000);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (0,'Description 6',5050);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (0,'Description 7',5150);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (0,'Description 8',5200);
INSERT INTO results VALUES (0,'Description 9',5341);
SELECT * FROM results;

Comment: If you run this above query and this is what my end goal result-set should look alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for `OUTER JOIN`, `INNER JOIN` will return rows that match between all conditions on two tables.

For this below query `RIGHT JOIN` will return rows based on `[dbo].[grtbk]` even conditions didn't match, But rows will be `NULL`
when the row didn't match by the conditions `GB.bdr_val`, so we need to use `ISNULL` in the aggregate function.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(ISNULL(GB.bdr_val,0)) AS Total_Material_M, 
    GR.oms25_0 AS Desc2, 
    GR.reknr AS Account
FROM
    [dbo].[gbkmut] GB 
RIGHT JOIN 
    [dbo].[grtbk] GR ON GB.reknr = GR.reknr
    AND GB.bkjrcode = 2021 
    AND GB.periode = 11 
GROUP BY 
    GR.oms25_0, GR.reknr
ORDER BY 
    GR.reknr ASC
```

Comment: I tried your query and it returned all the accounts(GB.reknr), not only the ones that I mentioned in the question. So I modified a little adding a WHERE condition after RIGHT JOIN,
WHERE GB.reknr = 5000 OR GB.reknr = 5050 OR GB.reknr = 5150 OR GB.reknr = 5200 
OR GB.reknr = 5210 OR GB.reknr = 5211 OR GB.reknr = 5250 OR GB.reknr = 5340 OR GB.reknr = 5341. Then again I'm ending up with the same result set I had, only 4 rows showing up for GB.reknr - 5210,5211,5250 and 5340.

Comment: You can try to let condition onto join condition instead of `where` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=17b35d934bf9005614aa131d23bc9463

Comment: I'm totally surprised and clueless, your query works perfect in the dbfiddle. Moreover that's exactly how I need the result set to be too. But when I copy it over to my SSMS it pulls all the 'GB.reknr' like 174 rows, not sure why even since we're specifically selecting those 9 'GB.reknr' numbers.

Comment: Thanks bunch dude, finally I found the working query for mine with little modification to your one.
SELECT
SUM(ISNULL(GB.bdr_val,0)) AS Total_Material_M,
GR.oms25_0 AS Desc2,
GR.reknr AS Account
FROM
[dbo].[gbkmut] GB
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
[dbo].[grtbk] GR ON GB.reknr = GR.reknr
AND GB.bkjrcode = 2021
AND GB.periode = 11
WHERE GR.reknr = 5000 OR GR.reknr = 5050 OR GR.reknr = 5150 OR
GR.reknr = 5200 OR GR.reknr = 5210 OR GR.reknr = 5211 OR
GR.reknr = 5250 OR GR.reknr = 5340 OR GR.reknr = 5341
GROUP BY
GR.oms25_0, GR.reknr
ORDER BY
GR.reknr ASC

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch around the order of the joins and change it to a `LEFT JOIN`. You also need to move the conditions for `GB` into the `ON` clause.

```sql
SELECT 
    SUM(GB.bdr_val) AS Total_Material_M, 
    GR.oms25_0 AS Desc2, GB.reknr AS Account
FROM
    dbo.grtbk GR
LEFT JOIN 
    dbo.gbkmut GB ON GB.reknr = GR.reknr
    AND GB.bkjrcode = 2021 
    AND GB.periode = 11 
    AND (GB.reknr = 5000 OR GB.reknr = 5050 OR GB.reknr = 5150 OR 
         GB.reknr = 5200 OR GB.reknr = 5210 OR GB.reknr = 5211 OR 
         GB.reknr = 5250 OR GB.reknr = 5340 OR GB.reknr = 5341)
GROUP BY 
    GR.oms25_0,
    GB.reknr
ORDER BY 
    GB.reknr ASC;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e872f6e1289022c26c7096bbe76d844)